# Reuse a Task List

Tags: tasks

I have a task list named **NEO Tasks**. This list contains a series of tasks to be completed by employees that have just completed their **N**ew **E**mployee **O**rientation. I want to be able to assign the set of tasks to each new employee as they complete the training. Is there a way to reuse an existing set of tasks where I can assign the tasks to new employees as they come onboard without having to recreate each task for each employee?

As an example:

**NEO Tasks:**

1. Set up your network account.
2. Set up your email signature.
3. Review the Security Policy document.
4. Review the Privacy Policy document.

Fred comes onboard June 01 so I assign all 4 tasks to him and watch for him to complete them. Aparna comes onboard August 01 - she needs to complete the same set of tasks so *I need to assign the same set of tasks to her.*

I do not want to put more than one employee name in the **Assigned To** field because then anyone could mark the task as Completed for the entire group; I need to be able to track each person's completion of each task. Nor do I want to re-assign the task because then I cannot track individual users.

Any thoughts or advice is greatly appreciated! Thank-you!

FYI, I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. I have used SharePoint Designer but am still a novice with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a site workflow using SharePoint Designer.

Inside workflow you can create the set of tasks items in the Tasks list. Also as part of Workflow initiation form collect the Assigned To detail and set that as you create task item.

Now as new Employees join you can just start this workflow.

1. Create new site workflow
2. Click on Initiation Form and Add single line of text and name it "AssignedTo"
3. Now inside Stage1 - From ribbon -> Actions -> Create Item
4. Click on this list and choose "Tasks"
5. Fill in required columns using Add button
6. For Assigning user - Click Add -> Field = "AssignedTo" -> Value -> Workflow Lookup for user -> Data Source = Workflow Variables and parameters -> Select AssignedTo

Do step 1 to 6 for number all the task items.

Comment: I just learned a ton about SPD from your post!! Thanks! I am running into a problem, though. For step 4, there is no "Tasks" on the list. There is, however, a group of items called "Task Actions" with the following options: Assign a Form to a Group, Assign a To-do Item, Collect Data from a User, Start Approval Process, Start Custom Task Process, & Start Feedback Process. I tried Custom Task Process but get an error message stating that "Office SharePoint Server Standard Site features must be enabled..." I activated the feature but continue to get the same error message. Any thoughts? Thanks!!